# looking for a value IF(ISERROR(MATCH function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have recovery and Resale sheets. If `recovery!A3` value matched within `Resale!B$2:B$10`, ] want to get the value of `Resale!G2`.
Formula is working fine for **A3 Cell** only, but when I drag it down and look for other matches between `recovery!A4` and `Resale next row`, It mess me up.

```
 =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A3,Resale!B$2:B$10,0))=FALSE,Resale!G2,"")
```

I want `Resale!G2` value only if `A3` **value=Resale!B2** which works after drag down.

[image]

Comment: in my formula Resale!G2 requires nested function which search and then get value after matching.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following, adjust range to cover your data.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Resale!$G$2:$G$5,MATCH(recovery!$A3,Resale!$B$2:$B$5,0)),"")
```

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem, please be sure to mark this as the accepted answer. It benefits you, QHarr, and the community as a whole.

Comment: @TotsieMae I am sorry to inform you that it requires 15 reputation to mark the accepted answer and i am a new user. Once i achieved i must mark it.

Comment: @MuhammadNaeem, as the asker you are always able to mark an answer as the accepted one on your own question. You can find the check mark under the down vote button associated with QHarr's answer. Please read this [information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more details. And welcome to the site! :-)